# Issue calling a SQL Server stored procedure from c# code

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which inserts at least 60 records into a table. When I run the stored procedure via Management Studio, it completes within a minute.

But via C#, the program gets stuck. No errors thrown.

I checked the database, there are no blocks. Please help me with any suggestions.

```
string sqlCommand = string.Empty;
sqlCommand = "SPname";
SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[1];
sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@UpdatedOn", lastRunTime);

try
{
    int result = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlCommand, sqlParam);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
}

public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string cmdText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandTimeout = GetCommandTimeOut();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, null, CommandType.StoredProcedure, cmdText, commandParameters);

        int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try running the profiler to see if sql server is receiving the command.

Comment: Consider posting code here. It might be possible you have problem there.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your SP called from C#?

Comment: Your C# connection will have a timeout. Have you changed this because the default, I think, is 1 minute. Therefore you code should throw an exception after 1 min because it has timed out.

Comment: it is not throwing timeout at all.  it just gets struck.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya : code attached.

Comment: Concider a `using` statement as well for the SQLCommand. It will not solve your current problem, but it will cleanup your code a bit. Are you sure it gets stuck on the `ExecuteNonQuery`? Put a `MessageBox` in your exception. Maybe you just miss the exceptions because it is turned off in your Debug settings

Comment: put a break point at `string sqlCommand = string.Empty;` and keep pressing F11....!

Comment: it is getting struck on executenonquery...